# IOC vs New guidelines

Tags: inversion-of-control

Recently I was looking at some source code provided by community leaders in their open source implementations. One these projects made use of IOC. Here is sample hypothetical code:

```
public class Class1
{
    private ISomeInterface _someObject;

    public Class1(ISomeInterface someObject)
    {
        _someObject = someObject;
    }

    // some more code and then

    var someOtherObject = new SomeOtherObject();
}
```

My question is not about what the IOCs are for and how to use them in technical terms but rather what are the guidelines regarding object creation. All that effort and then this line using "new" operator. I don't quite understand. Which object should be created by IOC and for which ones it is permissible to be created via the new operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, if something is providing a *service* which may want to be replaced either for testing or to use a different implementation (e.g. different authentication services) then inject the dependency. If it's something like a collection, or a simple data object which isn't providing behaviour which you'd ever want to vary, then it's fine to instantiate it within the class.

Comment: Thanks, just what the doctor ordered.

Answer (score 5):

Usually you use `IoC` because:

- A dependency that can change in the future
- To code against interfaces, not concrete types
- To enable mocking these dependencies in Unit Testing scenarios

You could avoid using `IoC` in the case where you don't control the dependency, for example an `StringBuilder` is always going to be an `StringBuilder` and have a defined behavior, and you usually don't really need to mock that; while you might want to mock an `HttpRequestBase`, because it's an external dependency on having an internet connection, for example, which is a problem during unit tests (longer execution times, and it's something out of your control).

The same happens for database access repositories and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help as well - just was I was looking for. Very clear explanation.